# Copy specific files listed in a CSV file

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm working in a Windows 2008 R2 Server and I'm trying to copy certain files listed in a csv file from one partition to another, headers are:

> ZipFile,Site.A,Site.B

ZipFile column contains the name of each file (name.zip).
Site.A column contains the full path where the file is at source.
Site.B column contains the full path where the file needs to be at the destination.

The code of the script is: (I've been looking on this site to get ideas)

```
$CSV_Path = "N:\File_with_paths.csv"
$CSV = Import-CSV $CSV_Path

ForEach ($File in $CSV) {
    Copy-Item -Path "$($File.'Site.A')$($File.'ZipFile')" -Destination "$($File.'Site.B')"  
}
```

It fails but I cannot see what the error is.  If I run it it shows an error for less than a second and the script does not copy any file.

Comment: You should be able to see your errors in the automatic `$Error` variable.

Comment: Did you missed the "\" in "$($File.'Site.A')-->\<--$($File.'ZipFile')"?

Answer (score 1):

To debug this, set a breakpoint for the `Copy-Item` cmdlet. This will let you step into debugging mode whenever your script reaches that particular command. If your script is named `myCopyScript.ps1`:

```
Set-PSBreakPoint -Script myCopyScript.ps1 -Command Copy-Item
.\myCopyScript.ps1
```

The script will now run until `Copy-Item` is invoked, at which point you will be inside the loop, but able to interact with the variables present.

This is a great opportunity to see what your $path name actually is:

```
Write-Host "$($File.'Site.A')$($File.'ZipFile')"
```

When you are done troubleshooting, remove the break point and exit the DEBUG prompt:

```
Get-PSBreakPoint | Remove-PSBreakPoint
Exit # This will simply stop the debugging nested prompt
```

---

If you in fact forgot the `\` between the source directory and the file name, here is a safer way of getting the full path to the file:

```
$SourceFile = Join-Path -Path $File.'Site.A' -ChildPath $File.ZipFile
```